# which channels of emotiv epoc to use for motor imagery?

Tags: emokit

I am working on a bci motor imagery project for my undergrad thesis.I use emotiv epoc and extract raw data with emokit from github https://github.com/openyou/emokit. I try to find which channels to use for a four class motor imagery (forwards,backwards,left,right).I guess i should use channels FC5,FC6,P3,P4 because they are the closest to the C3,C4,Cz channels, which are the best to use for motor imagery tasks but are absent at the emotiv headset. So which channels from the 14 available should i use?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the newest EPOC+??  because my epoc+ that in the serial number has "UD" instead of "GM" looks like the values that emokit gives me isn't correct.

I don't have the SDK from EMOTIV, so i can't compare values. I think it has something with the decryption key...   o.O!

for your problem, you can use the "Epoc Control Panel" in the option "Cognitive Suite" (free program) or the "Emotiv Xavier ControlPanel" in option "Detections/Mental Commands" ,  test your skills moving the square,  then when your brain has been trained, use the emokit and reproduce that train,  capture the signals, and thats all !!  you're gonna be able to use for your four class motor imagery (forwards,backwards,left,right).

https://emotiv.com/store/product_72.html

Check if the emokit is giving you the right values, put the emotiv epoc in the desk, and check the "mouse_control.py"  if the mouse moves, the values are wrong!

Mine was release in 08-03-15, working under Ubuntu , if yours work, tell me how you configured it please

Best Regards
Dracog71

Comment: I use the old EPOC purchased by a university professor in 2011. On the box it says: emotiv developer  edition sdk, emotiv epoc model 1.0 and the professor who bought the machine has printed a paper which says emotiv developer edition sdk v1.0.0.4.The developer edition doesn't provide anything to extract raw data.I posted a question on emotiv forum about this https://emotiv.com/forum/messages/forum15/topic18358/message35411/#message35411 .

Answer (score 0):

I have emotiv epoc developer edition sdk, emotiv epoc model 1.0 purchased by my professor in 2011.To get raw data i asked the emotiv forum and said i need to upgrade to reseach edition

emotiv.com/forum/messages/forum15/topic18358/message35411/#message35411 .

I get raw data from emokit by adding some lines to test.py . The data i get are integer values not float. The serial number i get in terminal is SN. Also i asked emotiv forum about channel selection and the answers i

got were not that satisfying emotiv.com/forum/messages/forum4/topic18335/message35325/#message35325

,but i will try and use F3,F4 channels. As about the mouse_control.py it won't run (something related to graphics card maybe) but i don't see a relation of it and getting right eeg data from emotiv.Have you posted an issue about your problem in github? Also to get features for classification from what i read around the internet it is necessery to do channel selection to reduce your feature vector dimensions. So my guess is that for motor imagery for example O1,O2 channels are irrelevant. Also check the emotiv data posted by https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00264 it might help you.